# Submitting apps to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

A client asked me to build an app for Android, which I have done and just pushed to Google, but I am know wondering if I have gone about this the right way.

I have used my own account, so the developer is listed as my company, when I think it should really be the clients company. It seems there is no way to have different companies per app, so when you go to the app in Google Play, it lists mine.

What do people generally do, create a new Google Developer account for each client app?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running a business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the clients google id and listed his application on the play store. Then I asked the client to change the password of his account and asked him to add my google account associated  with the applications. The developer console allows the owner to set permissions and share financial details and other options. This approach is best on my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Clients provides their Google play account and it is obvious when you are developing apps for different clients.

Comment: I try and get the client to do as little as possible, I think creating a separate account, under something like app+xxxx@ so all the emails go to one place might be the best idea.

Comment: and you can attach all email accounts to an email client to keep track of all emails at once until you want to handover that to app client.

Answer (score 1):

To me it would seem improper to create a new Google Developer account for each and every single client you obtain. This is my personal basis and how I approach the situation:

**When you should:**

- If the client is any of the following: a large corporation, established company or a
  professional startup, then brand identity is a key figure. In this
  situation it is advised that they have their own developer account.
- If they will be publishing or plan on publishing more then the
  initial app, it would be advised they have their own Developer
  account.

**When you shouldn't** (Things to Consider):

- Most often the general public doesn't even look at the developer
  listed because it is not as visible as the other information provided
  within the google play store. If the client does seek to be
  identified, a splash-screen would compensate and will generate more
  attention then the developer name located within the play store. Each
  time the target audience launches the app they will be exposed to the
  splash screen and will become more aware of the clients "identity"
  (e.j. Their fictitious name). Those who are downloading the app are
  seeking to download it for the service it provides, not for who
  really developed it. They just seek for a software solution. If it
  works, they'll download it.
- Most often your clients will not be familiar
  with the developer console and will hardly use it. It is more then likely
  that you will be contacted to maintain and update the app and other
  duties pertaining to using the developer console. On top of that the
  cons of creating a new account can cause setbacks if your client
  assigned a date for the app to be published. I have had an incident
  in the past where my developer account took 2 weeks to confirm and
  activate.
- Another problem would arises is if you are "contracted" to the client
  and must always provide future updates etc, having multiple different
  accounts for multiple different clients can become a hassle when your
  client base becomes large. It would be more convenient if majority of
  the apps are listed neatly within a single account.

**Most important thing to Consider**: At the end of the day, it all comes down to you providing the service to your client. Consult with your client and provide them the pros and cons of the situation and provide your insight to them based on your assessment of their situation and which would suit them more.

**Alternatives**: As mentioned in the other comments adding a user account is possible, however as note that the Users name will not be listed as the developer of the application. It just allows them access to the console.

Comment: A good amount of information, however I think when using the clients account you should get them to add you as a user as per user2833783 suggestion.

Comment: splash screen? please no to splash screens on Android - they're killing the platform

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add another user to manage the app. see this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

If you do everything by yourself, I would suggest to leave him out of it and invite another user on a need-to-know basis...